# How to load (multiple) defined Klarna payment methods?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-method, klarna, klarna-widget

I'm building a kind of sandbox integration of Klarna Payments (to get it working in principle and implement the logic later into a real shop). The first step described in the docu, the [session creating](https://developers.klarna.com/documentation/klarna-payments/integration-guide/create-session/), has worked. Now I'm trying to get the Klarna widget displayed.

The example in the [documentation](https://developers.klarna.com/documentation/klarna-payments/integration-guide/present-klarna-widget/#2-4-load-the-klarna-widget) shows, how to load one payment method (`pay_later` / invoice).

```
Klarna.Payments.load({
    container: '#klarna-payments-container',
    payment_method_category: 'pay_later'
  }, function (res) {
    console.debug(res);
})
```

I tried the same with `pay_now`, but it didn't work (Message "*Payment method not available*" on the page and `{show_form: false}` in the `res` object). And actually I want to see a form with three payment methods: `pay_now`, `pay_later`, and `pay_over_time`.

I took a look at the [documentation](https://x.klarnacdn.net/kp/lib/v1/index.html#load) of the `load()`. My expectation was to find a parameter like `payment_method_categories`. But the method only has `payment_method_category` and it needs to be a string...

**How to get a defined list of Klarna payment methods available and loaded?**

Probably some settings are in the Klarna backend / "control center" (Playground) or an API call for making the methods available are / is needed. If so, what needs to be done and how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Klarna Payments documentation is a bit confusing or I simply misunderstood it. Anyway, I thought, that the widget provides the (complete) form and that by following its steps I'm going to get the payment form. It's wrong. The widget only displays the block(-s) with the information about the payment method(-s). The actual form (the radio buttons and one or more buttons for the `authorize` call etc.) a concern of the implementer.

To get multiple defined Klarna payment methods following steps are needed:

`1` The methods need to be activated by Klarna for this (test) merchant account.

The available methods are listed in the response of the [session initialization call](https://developers.klarna.com/api/#payments-api-create-a-new-credit-session) (`POST /payments/v1/sessions`):

```
{
    "session_id": "...",
    "client_token": "...",
    "payment_method_categories": [
        {
            "identifier": "direct_bank_transfer",
            ...
        },
        {
            "identifier": "pay_later",
            ...
        },
        {
            "identifier": "pay_over_time",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

`2` Load the single payment blocks into separate HTML containers:

```
<script>
window.klarnaAsyncCallback = function () {
    Klarna.Payments.init({
        client_token: CLIENT_TOKEN
    });
    Klarna.Payments.load(
        {
            container: '#klarna-payments-container1',
            payment_method_category: 'pay_later'
        },
        function (res) {
            console.debug(res);
        }
    );
    Klarna.Payments.load(
        {
            container: '#klarna-payments-container2',
            payment_method_category: 'pay_over_time'
        },
        function (res) {
            console.debug(res);
        }
    );
    Klarna.Payments.load(
        {
            container: '#klarna-payments-container3',
            payment_method_category: 'direct_bank_transfer'
        },
        function (res) {
            console.debug(res);
        }
    );
};
</script>
<div id="klarna-payments-container1"></div>
<div id="klarna-payments-container2"></div>
<div id="klarna-payments-container3"></div>
```

The result should be look like this:

[image]

That's it. No visible form elements are provided (meaning: it *is* already the correct result). The implementer is responsible for the form and can now freely create and decorate a custom one.

Comment: Thanks for that information, that helped me well. Can you give me a hint where I can add the payment methods in the playground environment. At "store" I can only choose pay_later and I don't find any possibility to add another payment method...

Comment: Hi Alex, The methods need to be activated by Klarna for your merchant account.

Comment: Can someone explain why you have to ask Klarna to activate them? With Klarna Payments I only get pay_later and pay_over_time, but with Klarna Checkout I also get credit card payments and bank transfer using the same Klarna Playground credentials.